# DbContext Lifecycle In WCF Service Hosted In IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, ninject

I have been using Ninject for a while now and love what it brings to my code but I have run into a small dilemma and am unsure whether or not there is a problem or if I am overthinking it.

Scenario: WCF Service App hosted in IIS. EF6 RC1 as the ORM, injecting the DbContext derived class into my database class in my data library. Using JustMock (Telerik) to perform all of my unit testing, mocking the dbcontext that is injected into the db class to perform those particular unit tests.

Added

```
kernel.Bind<MyContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

per http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/03/27/managing-entity-framework-dbcontext-lifetime-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx to my Ninject module.

Service behavior of the WCF service is:

```
InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, UseSynchronizationContext = false
```

Per Dave Paquette's article, which was written for MVC4, not WCF, the lifecycle is handled through the registration of the OnePerRequestHttpModule (DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule)). When I added the Ninject WCF nuget package, the following was added to Start():

```
DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
```

My question is: What is the lifecycle of my dbcontext given that the WCF service exposes endpoints for namedpipes and TCP (no HTTP endpoints), its context more is PerSession, not PerCall and its hosted in IIS?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Received the following information from a Ninject guru:

The lifetime of InRequestScope in WCF is the same as OperationContext.Current. This means it is per WCF call. Scope cleanup is done by a IDispatchMessageInspector implementation. OnePerRequestHttpModule is not required in my case.

You should use PerCall ContextMode when using InRequestScope. Otherwise your service will access a disposed DbContext on the second call to the same session.

Comment: Where do you set the PerCall ContextMode? Thanks!

Comment: [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86007/ways-to-do-WCF-instance-management-Per-call-Per) shows how to set the context mode. Setting the context mode to PerCall fixed my problem of getting the error, "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed" when using the Ninject WCF extension (I just had to do a clean/rebuild before it worked).